# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows insert in single query

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates

I have a SQL query where I want to insert multiple rows in single query. so I used something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
  VALUES
  ('Helen', 24),
  ('Katrina', 21),
  ('Samia', 22),
  ('Hui Ling', 25),
  ('Yumie', 29)";

mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

The problem is when I execute this query, I want to check whether a `UNIQUE` key (which is not the `PRIMARY KEY`), e.g. `'name'` above, should be checked and if such a `'name'` already exists, the corresponding whole row should be updated otherwise inserted.

For instance, in the example below, if `'Katrina'` is already present in the database, the whole row, irrespective of the number of fields, should be updated. Again if `'Samia'` is not present, the row should be inserted.

I thought of using:

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
      VALUES
      ('Helen', 24),
      ('Katrina', 21),
      ('Samia', 22),
      ('Hui Ling', 25),
      ('Yumie', 29) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Here is the trap. I got stuck and confused about how to proceed. I have multiple rows to insert/update at a time. Please give me a direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 600, accepted):

Beginning with MySQL 8.0.19 you can use an alias for that row (see [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
    VALUES
    ('Helen', 24),
    ('Katrina', 21),
    ('Samia', 22),
    ('Hui Ling', 25),
    ('Yumie', 29)
    AS new
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    age = new.age
    ...
```

---

For earlier versions use the keyword `VALUES`  (see [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values), deprecated with MySQL 8.0.20).

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (name, age)
    VALUES
    ('Helen', 24),
    ('Katrina', 21),
    ('Samia', 22),
    ('Hui Ling', 25),
    ('Yumie', 29)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    age = VALUES(age),
     ...
```

Comment: Great suggestion. If you want to increment a value when duplicate, add this after the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" part: total = total + VALUES( total )

Comment: Caution: `The use of VALUES() to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated beginning with MySQL 8.0.20`. See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Caution: Don't use the variable name `new`

Comment: @harlekintiger They seem to use `new` in the manual that I linked. I don't work with MySQL though, so could you please elaborate why it should not be named `new`? Thank you!

Comment: @PeterLang of course, I should've specified the first time. While it does work and won't throw an error, at least for now, in MySQL 'new' is a reserved keyword [MySQL 8.0 Manual: 9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Please re-edit this post as it seems ambigous see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862505/mysql-multiple-upsert

Comment: @Datadimension: This answer also uses `VALUES` (deprecated) to address values that would have been inserted. Is anything wrong with the answer or was it missing information?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same behavior using jdbi's BindBeanList and found the syntax is exactly the same as Peter Lang's answer above. In case anybody is running into this question, here's my code:

```
  @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO table_one (col_one, col_two) VALUES <beans> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_one=VALUES(col_one), col_two=VALUES(col_two)")
void insertBeans(@BindBeanList(value = "beans", propertyNames = {"colOne", "colTwo"}) List<Beans> beans);
```

One key detail to note is that the propertyName you specify within `@BindBeanList` annotation is not same as the column name you pass into the `VALUES()` call on update.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will only work for MYSQL, not for SQL Server.

for SQL server, the way to work around this is to first declare a temp table, insert value to that temp table, and then use MERGE

Like this:

```
declare @Source table
(
name varchar(30),
age decimal(23,0)
)

insert into @Source VALUES
('Helen', 24),
('Katrina', 21),
('Samia', 22),
('Hui Ling', 25),
('Yumie', 29);


MERGE beautiful  AS Tg
using  @source as Sc
on tg.namet=sc.name 

when matched then update 
set tg.age=sc.age

when not matched then 
insert (name, age) VALUES
(SC.name, sc.age);
```

Comment: Original question is specifically about MySQL

Answer (score -1):

Let I have 2 tables in database: (1) brand (2) brand_item.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `brand`;
   CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_name` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disclaimer` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `terms` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `always_show_disclaimer` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disclaimer_instructions` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_instructions` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `terms_and_conditions_instructions` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_urls` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature` boolean DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `brand_key` (`brand_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `brand_item`;
CREATE TABLE `brand_item` (
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reward_name` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reward_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_whole_amount_value_required` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `face_value` double(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `min_value` double(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `max_value` double(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `redemption_instructions` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countries` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `utid` (`utid`),
  KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `brand_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand` (`brand_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Javascript code to insert into brand table :
**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is taken care of in INSERT query.**

```
async function addToDB(event, brandDetails) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

let values = `[brandDetails.key,brandDetails.name,brandDetails.disclaimer,brandDetails.description,brandDetails.shortDescription,brandDetails.terms,brandDetails.createdDate,brandDetails.lastUpdateDate,brandDetails.alwaysShowDisclaimer,brandDetails.disclaimerInstructions,brandDetails.displayInstructions,brandDetails.termsAndConditionsInstructions,brandDetails.imageUrls,brandDetails.status]` 

let query = "INSERT INTO ?? (brand_key,brand_name,disclaimer,description,short_description,terms,created_date,last_updated_date,always_show_disclaimer,       disclaimer_instructions,display_instructions,terms_and_conditions_instructions,image_urls,status) VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE brand_key=?, brand_name=?, disclaimer=?, description=?, short_description=?, terms=?, created_date=?,last_updated_date=?, always_show_disclaimer=?, disclaimer_instructions=?,\ display_instructions=?,terms_and_conditions_instructions=?, image_urls=?, status=?";

  MySQLController.executeQuery(event,query, [BRAND_TABLE, values, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7],values[8],values[9],values[10],values[11],values[12],values[13],values[14]] )
  .then((res)=>{
      console.log("Success in Insertion ", res);
      resolve(res);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("error in DB ",err);
      reject(err);     
  })

  })}
```

Javascript code to insert into brand_item table :
**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is taken care of in INSERT query.**

```
 async function addToBrandItem(event, fkey, brandItemDetails) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
       let values = [fkey, brandItemDetails.utid, brandItemDetails.rewardName, brandItemDetails.currencyCode, brandItemDetails.status, brandItemDetails.valueType, brandItemDetails.rewardType,brandItemDetails.isWholeAmountValueRequired, `${brandItemDetails.faceValue}`, `${brandItemDetails.minValue}`, `${brandItemDetails.maxValue}`, brandItemDetails.createdDate,brandItemDetails.lastUpdateDate,brandItemDetails.redemptionInstructions,`${brandItemDetails.countries}`]
      
  let query = "INSERT INTO ?? (brand_id,utid,reward_name,currency_code,status,value_type,reward_type,is_whole_amount_value_required,face_value,min_value,max_value,created_date,last_updated_date,redemption_instructions,countries) VALUES (?)";
  

  AuroraController.executeQuery(event,query , [BRAND_ITEM_TABLE, values, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7],values[8],values[9],values[10],values[11],values[12],values[13],values[14]] )
  .then((res)=>{
      console.log("Success in Insertion in Bran_item", res);
      resolve(res);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("error in DB ",err);
      reject(err);     
  })

  })}
```

**Note:-** To preserve decimal value in values array, I have tick symbol to get its value using `${}`, else it will consider as a string in array.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: Yes but using REPLACE the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. I want to retain the old row for maintaining primary ids.

Comment: I didn't realize that retaining the old PK is somehow important to you... Surely, REPLACE won't work in this case...

Comment: If you don't care about PK however, like in my case, this works perfectly.

Comment: PS: "replace into" requires both delete and insert privileges!

Comment: and for the above mentioned delete/insert reasons, its also much slower in these instances.

Comment: What if you want to update few columns? Replace will update all.