# Speed/best practice flushing mysqli_multi_query()

Tags: php, mysqli, benchmarking, mysqli-multi-query

I cringed when Sebastien stated he was disconnecting & reconnecting between each use of `mysqli_multi_query()` @ [Can mysqli_multi_query do UPDATE statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047348/mysqli-multi-query-vs-updates/22482699#22482699) because it just didn't seem like best practice.

However, Craig @ [mysqli multi_query followed by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945142/mysqli-mutli-query-followed-by-query) stated in his case that it was faster to disconnect & reconnect between each use of `mysqli_multi_query()` than to employ `mysqli_next_result()`.

I would like to ask if anyone has further first-hand knowledge or benchmark evidence to suggest an approximate "cutoff" (based on query volume or something) when a programmer should choose the "new connection" versus "next result" method.

I am also happy to hear any/all concerns not pertaining to speed. Does Craig's use of a connecting function have any bearing on speed?

Is there a speed difference between Craig's while statement:

```
while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;}
```

- versus -

a while statement that I'm suggesting:

```
while(mysqli_more_results($mysqli) && mysqli_next_result($mysqli));
```

- versus -

creating a new connection for each expected multi_query, before running first `multi_query`. I just tested this, and the two `mysqli_multi_query()`s were error free = no `close()` needed:

```
$mysqli1=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$pass","$db");
$mysqli2=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$pass","$db");
```

- versus -

Opening and closing between each `mysqli_multi_query()` like Sebastien and Craig:

```
$mysqli = newSQL();
$mysqli->multi_query($multiUpdates);
$mysqli->close();
```

- versus -

Anyone have another option to test against?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not `next_result()` to blame but queries themselves. The time your code takes to run relies on the time actual queries take to perform.

Although `mysqli_multi_query()` returns control quite fast, **it doesn't mean that all queries got executed by that time.** Quite contrary, by the time `mysqli_multi_query()` finished,  *only first query got executed.*  While all other queries are queued on the mysql side for the *asynchronous* execution.

From this you may conclude that `next_result()` call doesn't add any timeout by itself - it's just waiting for the next query to finish. And if query itself takes time, then `next_result()` have to wait as well.

Knowing that you already may tell which way to choose: if you don't care for the results, you *may* just close the connection. But in fact, it'll be just sweeping dirt under the rug, leaving all the slow queries in place. So, it's better to keep `next_result()` loop in place (especially because you have to check for errors/affected rows/etc. anyway) but speed up the queries themselves.

So, it turns out that to solve the problem with `next_result()` you have to actually solve the regular problem of the query speed. So, here are some recommendations:

1. For the select queries it's usual indexing/explain analyze, already explained in other answers.
2. For the DML queries, especially run in batches, there are other ways:

Speaking of Craig's case, it's quite much resembling the known problem of speed of innodb writes. By default, innodb engine is set up into very cautious mode, where no following write is performed until engine ensured that previous one were finished successfully. So, it makes writes awfully slow (something like only 10 queries/sec). The common workaround for this is to make all the writes at once. For insert queries there are plenty of methods:

- you can use multiple values insert syntax
- you can use LOAD DATA INFILE query
- you can wrap all the queries in a transaction.

While for updating and deleting only transaction remains reliable way. So, as a universal solution such a workaround can be offered

```
 $multiSQL = "BEGIN;{$multiSQL}COMMIT;";
 $mysqli->multi_query($multiSQL);
 while ($mysqli->next_result()) {/* check results here */}
```

If it doesn't work/inapplicable in your case, then I'd suggest to change `mysqli_multi_query()` for the single queries run in a loop, investigate and optimize the speed and then return to multi_query.

Comment: "multiple values insert syntax" - thanks by doing this my inserts were sped up by 40 times.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question:

### look before you jump

I expect your `mysqli_more_results()` call (the look before you jump), doesn't speed up things: If you have n results, you'll do (2*n)-1 calls to the database, whereas Craig does n+1.

### multiple connections

`multi_query` [executes async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6652908/383793), so you'll just be adding connection overhead.

### opening and closing db

Listen to [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22534822/383793) ;-) But don't loose track of what you're doing. Wrapping queries in a transaction, will make them [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)). That means, they *all fail*, or they *all succeed*. Sometimes that is *required* to make the database never conflict with your universe of discourse. But using transactions for speedups, may have unwanted side-effects. Consider the case where *one* of your queries violates a constraint. That will make the whole transaction fail. Meaning that if they weren't a logical transaction in the first place and most queries should have succeeded, that you'll have to find out which went wrong and which will have to be reissued. *Costing* you more instead of delivering a speedup.

[Sebastien](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21047348/383793)'s queries actually look like they should be part of some bigger transaction, that contains the deletion or updates of the parents.

## Instead, try and remember

### there is no spoon

In your examples, there was no need for multiple queries. The [INSERT ... VALUES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) form takes multiple tuples for VALUES. So instead of preparing one *prepared statement* and wrap its repeated executions in a transaction [like Your Common Sense suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22534822/383793). You could prepare a single statement and have it executed and auto-committed. As per [mysqli manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1689) this saves you a bunch of roundtrips.

So make a SQL statement of the form:

```
INSERT INTO r (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ...
```

and bind and execute it. `mysqldump` [--opt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) does it, so why don't we? The mysql reference manual as a [section on statement optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-optimization.html). Look in its DML section for insert and update queries. But understanding why `--opt` does what it does is a good start.

#### the underestimated value of preparing a statement

To me, the real value of prepared statements is *not* that you can execute them multiple times, but the automatic input escaping. For a measly single extra client-server round-trip, you save yourself from SQL injection. SQL injection is a serious point of attention especially when you're using `multi_query`. `multi_query` tells mysql to *expect* multiple queries *and execute* them. So fail to escape properly and you're in for some fun:

[image: Exploits of a mom]

So my best practise would be:

1. Do I *really* need multiple queries?
2. If I do, *escape* them well, or *prepare* them!

Comment: Although my answer does mention particular case of repeated insert, the *question* doesn't bear even a trace of it. And the matter of this question is too far away from both topics you had fancy to discuss in your answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've adjusted the answer to address the question more clearly.

Comment: That's interesting genre - a comment for other answer in the form of answer. Although you are making some points in it, you fail to answer particular question explicitly.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Interesting... perhaps a wiki answer would be better form.  I, don't quite get why I fail *deliberately*.  I'm not a native speaker.  Do you mean it in a different sense than say: „In TDD I deliberately make a test fail, *then* write the code to make it pass"?

Comment: Neither I am. I changed the word already. The question is, in essence: why next_result is so slow. The answer is: it's not next_result to blame.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the fallacies of my answer, by the way.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's our lot in life ;)

Comment: @ Chris Wesseling Thanks for taking the time to post.  To explain the reason for my general question... I am making the switch from mysql to mysqli for a client at work.  The project has php saving pdf-submitted data across four tables.  Programs are performing INSERT(some with a nested SELECT query to correct the pdf export value), SHOW, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE queries -- some of which are not simplistic in form.  I am currently using a mixture of single queries, multi_queries, and TRIGGERS.  For my usage, "Atomic" querying is fine; beneficial even.

Comment: While I am already employing a few layers of injection defense, I am finding myself very compelled to try Your Common Sense's https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql for the sake of defense and DRYness.  I guess I'll just have to apply it to some of the trickier queries to see it I can make it work for me.