# php, phpmyadmin - Error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysql, database, wampserver

I tried to upload my image using `PHP`, but I am currently faced with an error.

It shows:

> ErrorCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

Here's the code:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO toothresults (class, score, classifierID, classifierName, customClass, imageSource, image, username, dateposted) VALUES ('$class1', '$score1', '$classifierID1', '$classifierName1', '$customClass1', '$imageSource1', '$img', '$username1', '$datetime1');";
$sql1 .= "INSERT INTO toothfillingsresults (class, score, classifierID, classifierName, customClass, imageSource, image, username, dateposted) VALUES ('$class2', '$score2', '$classifierID2', '$classifierName2', '$customClass2', '$imageSource2', '$img', '$username2', '$datetime2');";
$sql1 .= "INSERT INTO gumresults (class, score, classifierID, classifierName, customClass, imageSource, image, username, dateposted) VALUES ('$class3', '$score3', '$classifierID3', '$classifierName3', '$customClass3', '$imageSource3', '$img', '$username3', '$datetime3')";

//if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql1)){
if (!mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql1)){
    die('Error' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
//die;
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: I believe you will find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715889/strict-standards-mysqli-next-result-error-with-mysqli-multi-query/22469722#22469722  Keep in mind, if you are INSERTing user input, then you should use prepared statements with placeholders and there is no shame in running your three queries separately in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `mysqli_multi_query()` then it is fair for me to assume that you have previously called one or more queries previously in the script.

If you have called a single query use:

```
$mysqli->next_result();  // this will flush the one result
```

If you have called multiple queries via mysqli_multi_query()` use:

```
while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;}  // this will flush all of the results
```

Once the previous results are flushed out, you can call new single/multiple queries

For more reading, go here:  [Speed/best practice flushing mysqli_multi_query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531943/speed-best-practice-flushing-mysqli-multi-query)