# Does my sql query continue executing after i been disconnected due to long operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

If I run a SQL query in MySQL workbench and the connections time out after 30 seconds because it is taking a long time. Does my Query continue executing on the MySQL server even though I am disconnected?

For example, if I am doing an update and the update loops over a billion records. Does the MySQL server disconnect me first then it finishes the query after?  Or does it disconnect me and terminate the query?

Comment: You can find this out for yourself. You have MySQL Workbench, just look at the "Administration" Tab and under the MANAGEMENT section look at "Client Connections"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. As Mustafa mentioned, you can see the query still running if you look at "Administration tab" -->  Management --> Client Connections.

Also good to remember that you can change the 30sec cap to longer, shorter or none.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MySQL Workbench can disconnect and the query keeps running. This has been reported as a bug, but it's in the "Verified" state, which means it is not fixed: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78809

See also this related SO thread: [MySQL Query running even after losing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625362/mysql-query-running-even-after-losing-connection)

If you have a long-running query that needs to do a bulk update, you may need to change the MySQL Session timeout options in the MySQL Workbench preferences. Alternatively, don't use MySQL Workbench for long-running jobs, use the `mysql` command line tool.