# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with a WHERE and COUNT condition...?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I would have liked to use a WHERE statement on a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement in MySQL, however I understand you can't do this. I wanted my statement to be something like this..

```
INSERT INTO table1(name, user, num_users) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
num_users = SELECT COUNT(users.table2) WHERE name=%s)
(name, user, 1, name))
```

So if anyone know how to do this in one command that would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are actually trying to solve. It's hard to tell what you expect the code to do, especially when the parenthesis don't match.

Comment: I highly doubt your desired syntax possible, but you can use a trigger to do it.

Comment: please take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WHERE`, and a subquery, in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. Try using the correct syntax for that `SELECT`. I think this is wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(users.table2) WHERE name=%s
```

Is table2 a table? In that case, there's something totally wrong. If it is a field, just try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(table2) FROM users WHERE name=%s
```