# MySQL on duplicate - Insert but do not update

Tags: mysql, database, insert, sql-update, on-duplicate-key

I have an SQL query that looks like this (WordPress options).

```
INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES
(
    'category_children',
    'a value',
    'yes'
),
(
    'test_options',
    'testing',
    'yes'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    option_name=option_name,
    option_value=option_value,
    autoload=autoload
;
```

**What is does**

It inserts the values correctly but if I run it again with different values I expect it to update the values to the new ones.

**What it don't do**

It does not update the values the second time I run the query. I change the values. I get SQL no errors. 0 rows affected.

**What it should to**

If I change "a value" to "some other value" and run the query the value should be replaced if category_children already exists.

**Question**

What I'm I doing wrong? I use mysql 5.5.24.

Comment: Maybe duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating `option_name` to `option_name` will have no effect. You can use the `VALUES` syntax to update to the value from the insert:

```
INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES
(
    'category_children',
    'a value',
    'yes'
),
(
    'test_options',
    'testing',
    'yes'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    option_name=VALUES(option_name),
    option_value=VALUES(option_value),
    autoload=VALUES(autoload)
;
```