# MySQL - Insert Multiple Records or Update Multiple Records If Exists

Tags: mysql

I want to ***INSERT*** a new record into my database if it is no exists, otherwise it will ***UPDATE*** those existing records.

I did search on Stackoverflow, but none of the result can solve my issue.

- ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update?rq=1)
- [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows insert in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query)

**TABLE STRUCTURE**
[image]

**SCENARIO**

There are a lot of records inside *Purchase Details* table. So the only **Unique ID** is only *purchase_id*.

I want to update the *amount* which have the same *product_id*. Refer to the table.

[image]

Below is the SQL Query I have tried so far.

```
INSERT INTO `purchase_details` (`product_id`, `amount`)
VALUES (1583, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = 0
```

The query shows **1 row affected**.

But total has **146 rows** which mean this query is not working.

**PROBLEM**

1. **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** only allow to inserted a row that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Can you post your attempts? What is your criterion for updating the `amount` column?

Comment: @SameerMirji, I updated my format.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query)

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu, I read it already. It's not working.

Comment: If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row. purchase_id is your PK so I believe it's auto incremental..so your insert will never going to produce duplicate row..`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will not help here :(

Comment: @JimishGamit, so the only way is to use PHP and use LOOP to update? :(

Comment: Can you please elaborate more clearly which records you want to update and when you want to insert ? examples will be good to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to `update` the other existing rows of your table which have the same `product_id` as the new one being inserted with the newly provided `amount` value.

Since `product_id` is not a `unique` column in `purchase_details` table, it will not consider this scenario for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` condition. Ergo, 1 row affected.

To achieve what you want, you need to [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ins_check 
AFTER INSERT ON purchase_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE purchase_details
       SET amount = NEW.amount
     WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Sameer, thank you. Let me give it a try and let you know.