# VBA MySQL Several queries in one Execute

Tags: mysql, vba, ado, adodb

I'm programming a tool which grabs data from local systems and then sends data to MySQL database. Now, it's running on Access DB, but it's very time-consuming to merge data from few local databases (it's running on some computers).

I decided to move to MySQL, connection works as well executing single queries.
But doing that in this way is not time-acceptable (for my data batch - 1,5 second to add data to accdb and almost 80 seconds to add the same to MySQL).

**I'm aware that remote MySQL database will never be so fast as local Access DB (MySQL DB is on shared hosting, it's my private project).**

I talked to my friend who is PHP & MySQL dev and he told me that running queries at batch would shorten the execution (e.g. execute 100 queries in one time instead of 100 single executions).

I modified my script to do so, but if I try to execute multiple queries I have **Syntax Error** (***when I paste the same query into phpMyAdmin immediate window it works, so this is not syntax***).

I read that ADODB Connection (which I use) cannot execute multiple queries - but if there any alternative?

I could write little console .NET application which reads .sql files and then executes a batch query, but first I want to be sure if it's **really** necessary.

My connection is declared

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=SERVER;Database=DB_NAME;Uid=DB_USER;Pwd=DB_PWD;Option=3" 

strQuery = "CREATE TABLE Z AS (SELECT * FROM tblOffers WHERE 1=2); CREATE TABLE ZZ AS (SELECT * FROM tblOffers WHERE 1=2);"
cn.Execute (strQuery)
```

These queries are just for testing - I'm not creating new tables in my project, but upsering data (insert or update if duplicate).

My single query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblOffers (`TITLE`, `LINK`, `IMG`, `PRICE`, `DATE`, `PLATFORM`, `OFF_ID`, `LOCATION_ID`) 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT "Zgrywus PC", "https://www","zgrywus-pc-znin.jpg",10,'2017-07-08',"PC","6hZH9","0929865") As Tmp 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE `TITLE` = "Zgrywus PC", 
`LINK` = "https://www", 
`IMG` = "zgrywus-pc-znin.jpg", 
`PRICE` = 10, 
`DATE` = '2017-07-08', 
`PLATFORM` = "PC", 
`OFF_ID` = "6hZH9", 
`LOCATION_ID` = "0929865";
```

EDIT: @joanolo, here's full code snippet:

```
Sub ExportDataToAccess()

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim strQuery As String, strClrQuery As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=SERVER;Database=DB;Uid=UN;Pwd=PWD;Option=3"
    strQuery = "CREATE TABLE Z AS (SELECT * FROM tblOffers WHERE 1=2); CREATE TABLE ZZ AS (SELECT * FROM tblOffers WHERE 1=2);"
    Debug.Print strQuery
    cn.Execute (strQuery)


    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

And produced error is:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdj4L.jpg)

**EDIT2, 10-07-2017**

I decided to run [multiple row INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query) - it works - so my problem is resolved, **but if anyone would have any solve for issue of this topic, please share.**

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the code that produces the *Syntax error*?

Comment: @joanolo I edited first post.

Comment: does this work ?  `CREATE TABLE abc ( a CHAR  , b char  );CREATE TABLE xyz ( a CHAR  , b char );`

Comment: @jsotola - I think that's issue specific for ADODB connection and these types of queries cannot be executed at once. This error could be only fixed by changing vba code, not SQL.

Comment: that is why i asked you to try a really simple create table query. because if that does not work, then a more complicated query will not work either.

Answer (score 1):

@Krukosz - I had the same question today, I solved it on another way. Well you can execute each command in a ForEach- oder other Loop, separated/splitted by the 'virtual' Dash-Comma ';' you use in 'normal' SQL-Statements not in VBA. It's cool that you can use vars over more Execute's.

Here is an example code, and @start will be 1082 in the end of this example. But it seems to remember vars only for a few minutes. If you wait 5 minutes and try the last row again, the value of @start will be 'Null'.

```
Set rst = dbc.Execute("SET @start = 898")
Set rst = dbc.Execute("SET @start = @start+184 ")
Set rst = dbc.Execute("SELECT @start,'test'")
..
.
```