# MySQL Query error - no data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-update

I'm relatively new to MySQL, and I'm trying to combine my insert and update statements like I saw elsewhere.  For the following code,

```
$query = "this is not the problem";
$ora_stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$result = oci_execute($ora_stmt);
$stmt1 = $mysqli1->prepare("INSERT INTO na_dslam_card (n_alias, shelf_pt_num, card_pt_num, card_pt_description)
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE n_alias=?, shelf_pt_num=?, card_pt_num=?, card_pt_description=?");

while($row = oci_fetch_array($ora_stmt, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print  $row['DSLAM'] . "," . $row['MODEL']  . "," . $row['VENDOR'] . "," . $row['BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID'] . "," . $row['SVC_N'] . "," . $row['PORT_ADDR_STATUS']. "," . $row['BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID'] . "," . $row['RACK'] . "," . $row['SHELF'] . "," .  $row['SLOT'] . "," . $row['PORT'] . "," . $row['SHELF_PT_NUMBER'] . "," .  $row['CARD_PT_NUMBER'] . "," . $row['CARD_PT_DESCRIPTION'] . "\n";
    $stmt1->bind_param("ssss", $row['DSLAM'],$row['SHELF_PT_NUMBER'],$row['CARD_PT_NUMBER'],$row['CARD_PT_DESCRIPTION']); 
    if(!$stmt1->execute())
    { 
      $tempErr = "Error setting card info: " . $stmt1->error;
      printf($tempErr . "\n");  //show mysql execute error if exists  
      $err->logThis($tempErr);
    } 
} //while
```

I get this error message:

> Error setting card info: No data supplied for parameters in prepared
>   statement

I used bind_parameters, so it shouldn't say I didn't supply the parameter data. I know rack can be null sometimes, but wouldn't it just set it to null in that case? I know the oracle query works because the print statement shows this:

> CNVLDAT00,TA12,Ad,196,641,In Service,196,,2,,7,117,115,11L5

So why are the parameters not supplied correctly? It looks ok to me.

I looked at [insert values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query) and I think I'm doing that ok.

My table looks like this:

na_dslam_card:
index
n_alias
shelf_pt_num
card_pt_num
card_pt_description

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are eight bind placeholders in the SQL text. We would need to supply eight values.

The bind_param is only supplying four values.

But rather than supply eight values, we can modify the SQL text to replace the placeholders in the UPDATE clause with the `VALUES()` function, to reference the value that would have been inserted into the column.

```
INSERT INTO na_dslam_card
( n_alias
, shelf_pt_num
, card_pt_num
, card_pt_description
)  
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE n_alias             = VALUES(alias)
     , shelf_pt_num        = VALUES(shelf_pt_num)
     , card_pt_num         = VALUES(card_pt_num)
     , card_pt_description = VALUES(card_pt_description)
```

Now there are only four placeholders that need values.

---

Excerpt from MySQL Reference Manual:

> In assignment value expressions in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, you can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. In other words, `VALUES(col_name)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause refers to the value of `col_name` that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: So it looks funny for me that the UPDATE n_alias             = VALUES(alias)
     , shelf_pt_num        = VALUES(shelf_pt_num)
     , card_pt_num         = VALUES(card_pt_num)
     , card_pt_description = VALUES(card_pt_description) has the same variable on both sides of the equals sign.  Is that right? The excerpt does say col_name, so I guess it's right.

Comment: That's not a variable inside the `VALUES()` function... it's a reference to a column. It references the value that would have been inserted into the column. If any of these columns are part of the primary key or unique key, we probably don't need to update that. For example, if n_alias is the PRIMARY KEY on the table, we could omit the assignment to n_alias in the UPDATE clause.