# Trying to update an existing record - getting an error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert records into my DB, if a duplicate is found it should only update one field.

This is my code so far

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO ppage_image_uploads(Cons_ID, Img_SRC, Program, TeamRaiser_ID) 
    VALUES
    ('" . $_POST["cons_id"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["img_src"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["program"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["tr_id"] . "')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        Img_SRC = VALUES '" . $_POST["img_src"] . "'
    )";
```

Took this loosely from another question: [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows insert in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query)

I'm ending up with an error message from my page that handles this script saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''theimageurl.jpg' )' at line 8

Does anything look wrong in that statement that I'm missing?

Comment: Remove that `VALUES`.

Comment: @JimmyB the values in the update statement?

Comment: Yes, `VALUES` from `Img_SRC = VALUES`.

Comment: You might want to research SQL injection and what you can do about it ... i suggest you to read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JimmyB thank you very much! That did the trick, initial record commits and then a second attempt only updates the image. Exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

There is an unmatched closing parenthesis at the end of your sql query.

The `VALUES` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause can be used to refer to the value that would have been inserted if no duplicate key conflict had happened, as explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO ppage_image_uploads(Cons_ID, Img_SRC, Program, TeamRaiser_ID) 
    VALUES
    ('" . $_POST["cons_id"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["img_src"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["program"] . "',
    '" . $_POST["tr_id"] . "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Img_SRC = VALUES(Img_SRC)";
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB for the response. Still getting the same error though unfortunately

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000: I updated the query, would you please check again?