# MySQL multiple upsert

Tags: upsert, mysql-8.0

I have viewed many many posts regarding this and they seem to obfusticate multiple columns, also where there should be unquoted values eg:

[MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows insert in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query)

From my humble understand (which is wrong as there is an error) here is my full statement for a test table

```
insert into testDB (`UUID`,`description`,`created_at`,`updated_at`)
values ('6','test 6a',now(),now()),('7','test 7a',now(),now())
on duplicate key update
UUID = VALUES('6','7'),
description = VALUES('test 6a','test 7a'),
created_at = VALUES(now(),now()),
updated_at = VALUES(now(),now())
```

This is the most basic I can get the example, the column type for created_at and updated_at is obviously datetime

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''6','7'), description = VALUES('test 6a','test 7a'), created_at = VALUES(now(),n' at line 1
```